# ImageView Inflation

Tags: android, imageview, inflate

I am attempting to create multiple copies of a single image.  While debugging, everything seems fine until I try stepping past the line `ImageView image = ...` -- program stops and gives me a **Source not found** error (tab title: *ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1953*).
I am completely frustrated with this... *Can anyone tell me why this happens???*

## Main.java

```
package languid.legend.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

/**
 * @author Adam
 * 
 */
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-1, 345);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // getting access to laytou inflater

        View[] tiles = new ImageView[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
            // Creating copy of imageview by inflating it
            ImageView image = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleimage, null);
            tiles[i] = image;
            tiles[i].setId(100+i);
            params.leftMargin = 32 * 2 * i;
            params.topMargin = 34 * 2 * i;
            layout.addView(tiles[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</RelativeLayout>
```

## singleimage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="Sample"
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am not sure but if you're trying to inflate an ImageView the root element of the xml file should be ImageView not a relativelayout.

Comment: Are you referring to the `ImageView image = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleimage, null);` line?  If so, isn't `null` the root?

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace for the error here. then I can help better.

Comment: Also, I mean the root element in the singleImage.xml I guess should be ImageView rather than RelativeLayout.